# define a constant instead of duplicating 5 times

Tags: node.js, sonarqube

I'm fairly new to Node.js and I am having some issues.
I received error in sonarqube as define a constant instead of duplicating 5 times for "-deleteFlag". how can i resolved this issue.

```
export class CCGuid {
  "-deleteFlag": string;
  "#text": string;

  constructor(obj: any) {
    if (typeof obj === "string") {
      this["#text"] = obj;
      this["-deleteFlag"] = "N";
    } else {
      try {
        this["-deleteFlag"] = obj["-deleteFlag"];
      } catch {
        this["-deleteFlag"] = undefined;
      }
      try {
        this["#text"] = obj["#text"];
      } catch {
        this["#text"] = undefined;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
export class CCGuid {
  "-deleteFlag": string;
  "#text": string;

  constructor(obj: any) {
    const deleteFlag = "-deleteFlag";
    if (typeof obj === "string") {
      this["#text"] = obj;
      this[deleteFlag] = "N";
    } else {
      try {
        this[deleteFlag] = obj[deleteFlag];
      } catch {
        this[deleteFlag] = undefined;
      }
      try {
        this["#text"] = obj["#text"];
      } catch {
        this["#text"] = undefined;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I think this should do the trick with SQ, at least when it comes to that particular variable. You can do the same with `"#text"` of course.

---

After edit: sorry my first answer was broken, I was in a rush and didn't realize what I was really writing down.

Given my updated snippet, you can do the following:

`this[deleteFlag']`: This will work.

`this['-deleteFlag']`: This will of course work but Sonar Qube will complain because your use of duplicated string literals.

`this.deleteFlag`: This won't work because would be looking for a `deleteFlag` key on the object. Such key doesn't exist, it's `'-deleteFlag'`.

`this['deleteFlag']`: this is functionally the same as the line above. Would look for a `'deletFlag'` key on the object, which doesn't exist.

Sorry for the confusion! Hope this helps now

Comment: can we use this.deleteFlag like this['deleteFlag'] or this[deleteFlag]

Comment: Ey sorry updated my answer with more info and fixing the issue

Comment: Any other way to implement this logic. This way my code breaking